# Laravel 5: can't set date from string

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

On my db migration i have a "dob" field:

```
$table->date('DOB')->nullable();
```

I have a string representing a date: "12/12/1960" in the input. I tested "dob" and the content is there. But when I try to set it to the "dob" field in the database..

```
$member->DOB = date('m/d/Y',Request::input('dob'));
```

The datebase field becomes `0000-00-00`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database most likely wants it in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. So just changing the format should work. But to get from `12/12/1960` to there, you need to parse it.

```
$oldDateString = '12/12/1960';
$newDateString = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $oldDateString)->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at definition
string date ( string format [, int timestamp] )
Second parameter is timestamp, not string
Use DateTime PHP5 functions or Laravel Carbon

E.g. date_create_from_format('m/d/Y', Request::input('dob'))
                        ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');